# How do I share global variables in a shared library(.so) across the processes that use the same shared library?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to count the number of different processes using the shared library by defining the static global variable on the top of the library. Created a shared library, os.so and calling it from main.c. Code as follows.

```
///  cat os.c
#include <stdio.h>

static  int count = 0;

void incre() {
++count ;
printf("Process using os.so is %d\n",count);
}
```

gcc -c -fpic os.c
   gcc -shared os.o -o os.so

/// cat main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void main() {

void (*ptr2) (void); 
void *handle;

 handle = dlopen("./os.so", RTLD_NOW);
if (handle == NULL) {
 printf("failed to open library\n");
 exit(2);
}

 ptr2 = dlsym(handle,"incre");

ptr2();
getchar();
dlclose(handle);
}
```

gcc main.c -ldl produces a.out

Now I am running 2 different instances of a.out in separate shells. Surprisingly, I am getting the output same as "Process using os.so is 1 " from both the processes. Since count is an global variable, I am expecting it to incremented in the shared library address space.

Also I observed from the output /proc/pid/maps for both the processes that they are referring to same file descriptor of os.so.

```
# cat /proc/1943/maps 
00920000-00921000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 298166     /home/user1/personal/programs/logic /libraries/os.so 


# cat /proc/1944/maps 
00152000-00153000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 298166     /home/user1/personal/programs/logic   /libraries/os.so
```

My question is why the global data is not shared for all the processes which uses os.so?

If I declare static variable in `incre()` in os.so, still it is not shared?
Is it the same with windows dll's also?

Comment: Note the `p` in `r-xp`. That means a private mapping, which is copied-on-write. You need a shared mapping, which you can get via shared memory (either SYSV shm, mmap MAP_SHARED of a file, or shm_open + mmap).